# Are there any online resources that are freely availible, on Complex Analysis, that you recommend?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, self-learning, online-resources

I am quite interested in learning more Complex Analysis, or Complex Function Theory as it is sometimes called. I have self-studied approximately a typical undergraduate introductory complex analysis course. Are there any particular web resources, that can be self-studied, that you can recommend?

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A very good and readable introduction is the *Introduction to Complex Analysis* by Michael Taylor, see http://www.unc.edu/math/Faculty/met/complex.pdf. It covers every standard topic on complex analysis that any maths student should have covered, as well as several more advanced complex analysis topics such as *elliptic functions*, *covering maps* or *Riemann surfaces*. Furthermore, an appendix is included, and Taylor also provides a lot of exercises within his script. Very recommendable in my opinion!

Answer (score 1):

The lecture notes by Terry Tao: [Complex Analysis for Applications](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/resource/general/132.1.00w/).